# Facebook calling Google App Engine code using GET instead of POST

Tags: python, google-app-engine, facebook

I've been developing a Facebook app using Google App Engine in Python and the [pyfacebook bindings](http://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook). For weeks everything worked fine but suddenly it stopped.

At first I thought it was a code change so I rolled back the entire dev directory to a version I knew worked, but still it failed.  It's possible a change I made to the application's settings caused the issue but, if so, I can't figure out what.

I've figured out that the problem is that instead of calling the post(self) method of my Main class, Facebook is calling using a GET.

Does anyone know why Facebook would use a GET method instead of a POST? It's an IFrame app.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not completely sure this was the cause, it appears I changed from an FBML app to an IFrame app.  FBML mode relies on POST calls but IFrame appears to use GET. I'm inferring this answer from [what I read here](http://dollarmani-facebook.blogspot.com/2008/09/using-facebook-api-in-python.html) as well as from the observations I'm seeing and this being the only answer that makes any sense.

Answer (score 1):

The typical flow for a user when using the application begins with the user landing at some Canvas URL, like http://apps.facebook.com/runwithfriends/. At this point, Facebook will load up it's chrome, and render a  tag to your application. You'll notice there isn't a src specified. Using some JavaScript and the  tag, Facebook triggers a POST request to your application. This is done for security reasons, as the sensitive user data won't be sent via the HTTP Referrer header as long it's sent as POST data.